# How can I use Liaison API(LAPI) of sita gabriel in c# or any language?

Tags: c#, windows-7, exe, windows, ocx

I'm found LAPI.ocx in installed directory of Liaison sita gabriel (Airline ticketing system) and add it to my application. but don't exist any document or manual and I don't know how work it.
So, when i use connect method rais an error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in airtixWinApp.exe
```

I'm using windows 7 and see airtixWinApp.vshost.exe but don't see airtixWinApp.exe.
I'm confused to using this OCX...
Please help me

Comment: [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: My question is about using LAPI and how to use it, this ocx is only way to communicate with sita gabriel system and don't exist any document about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is LAPI.html in the same folder. It has some example which I am also trying to use but so far only managed to connect to a session preconfigured in my Liaison installation.

Here is my code so far, which I simply created in an .hta file.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    var objLAPI = new ActiveXObject("LiaisonAPI.ctlLAPI");
    if (objLAPI)
    {
        document.write("<div>LAPI Created</div>");
    }
    else
    {
        document.write("<div>LAPI Failed</div>");
    }
    var sessions = objLAPI.GetSessionNames();
    objLAPI.Session = "DYNQAA";
    var objConn = objLAPI.Connect();
    if (!objConn) 
    {
        document.write("Connection Failed");
    } else {
        document.write("<div>Connected</div>");
    }

    var strDynPID = objLAPI.DynamicPID;
    document.write(sessions + strDynPID);

    document.write("<hr>");
    objLAPI.Disconnect();
</script>
```

It work, but I am yet to figure out how to post actual commands to the terminal and read out its output.

If you do succeed, please kindly let us know.

Thank you
Regards
Alex